# Model.predict tensorflow shape is read incorrectly

Tags: tensorflow, sequential

I started making a sequential network using tensorflow for food classification.
When I created the simplest model I faced a following issue: model.predict(images[99]) was giving me an issue :
`Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4096, but received input with shape (32, 64)`.
It happened even though
`images[99].shape 99`

images is a data, where every element of the list is an image with one channel.
`images.shape (10099, 64, 64)`

Model:
`

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(64,64)),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation=tf.nn.relu),

    
    keras.layers.Dense(101, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

])
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
metrics = \['accuracy'\])


model.fit(images_tr, categories_tr, epochs=2)
```

`it also looks absurd to me because when I try:`
model.predict(np.zeros((64, 64))`
I get the same issue

Also when I do evaluation `model.evaluate(images)` it works perfectly fine.

I have tried to change version of tensorflow from 2.9.0 to 2.2.2, that didn't help.

Comment: There is no issue, you are missing the samples/batch dimension. So to input a single 64x64 value, the shape should be (1, 64, 64).

Comment: It's a typical mistake, but not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

that is because it selected one from the received value shape and the smallest that can be filled is 32, you can do something as this for creating a flexible layer the shape is by your conditions.

Sample: You may calculate the input shape for the target layer as in the sample.

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
start = 3
limit = 12291
delta = 3

# Create DATA
sample = tf.range( start, limit, delta )
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.int64 ).numpy()
sample = tf.constant( [sample, sample], shape=( 2, 4096, 1 ) )

label = tf.constant([[0.2, 0.8, 0.8], [0.0, 0.0, 0.8]], dtype=tf.float32)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])                      # (4096, 1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
        return temp

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( int(sample.shape[-2] / 64), 64, 1 ))
layer_01 = MyDenseLayer(3)
        
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    input_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(36, activation='relu'),
    layer_01,
])

model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(sample, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(2, 1, 64, 64), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(label, shape=(2, 3, 1), dtype=tf.float32)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    label_smoothing=0.0,
    axis=-1,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='binary_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=10, epochs=5 )


predictions = model.predict(tf.constant(sample[1,:,:], shape=(1, int(sample.shape[-2] / 64), 64, 1)))
print( predictions )
```

Output: 3 dots controls rotor communication wireless.

```
Epoch 1/10000
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 10.8326 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10000
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 10.8326 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[[ 0.0, 1.0, 0.8 ]]
```